# Оптимальный алгоритм упаковки сообщений разной длины в контейнеры

Tags: php, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Есть у нас набор сообщений (80 штук) длиной от 3 до 70 символов. Есть определенные контейнеры, в которые может входить произвольное кол-во сообщений, но их суммарная максимальная длина ограничена 100 символами. Помогите найти оптимальный (с точки зрения быстродействия в том числе) алгоритм, при котором все сообщения могут быть размещены в минимальном числе контейнеров.

Answer (score 2):

[Метод упаковки рюкзака.](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_о_ранце)

Comment: Сто пудов учебная задача. И еще смотри, чего хотят от бедного студента:

> Помогите найти оптимальный (с точки зрения быстродействия в том числе) алгоритм

Оптимальный алгоритм для NP задачи им подавай. Хоть гипотезу Римана доказать не просят, и то сахар.

Comment: Да нет, здесь же не один рюкзак. Больше подходит задача об упаковке в контейнеры оттуда же, но у меня простой одномерный случай а такие алгоритмы там не рассмотрены.

Comment: Ну, вы можете упаковать один рюкзак, потом второй. И так далее, пока фразы не закончатся. Вам доказать, что это будет оптимальная упаковка с точки зрения числа контейнеров?  
Насчет производительности... @alienator прав, ой прав. =) Но думаю, мой вариант прокатит.

Comment: Не, отдельные рюкзаки ты упаковывать не предлагай. Когда контейнеров несколько, задача немножко другая. Алгоритмы (best fit, first fit) легко нагугливаются.

Comment: Нет, задача не учебная, в том-то и дело. Задача вполне реальна и очень важна экономически. Я ее несколько абстрагировал конечно. Но нагрузка предполагается колоссальная, поэтому так важна оптимизация произоводительности и минимизация числа контейнеров. Ладно, попробую нагуглить ваши алгоритмы best fit, first fit.

Answer (score 1):

В чистом виде [задача об упаковке](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5#.D0.97.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B0_.D0.BE.D0.B1_.D1.83.D0.BF.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B5) (англ. Bin Packing Problem). Отличается от задачи о рюкзаке на словах совсем немного, но с точки зрения решения - очень сильно.

Эта задача является NP-трудной - то есть полиномиальное решение не найдено. Динамическим программированием эта задача также не решается - так что искать решение следует или перебором - или же можно плюнуть на оптимальность решения и искать субоптимальное эвристиками.

Теперь по поводу этих самых эвристических алгоритмов. Переписываю с [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B), чтобы не надо было искать.

Сообщения сортируются в порядке убывания размера. Потом каждое сообщение последовательно пытаются запихнуть в имеющиеся контейнеры, если не получается - создают новый контейнер и кладут в него.

Алгоритм First Fit Decreasing (FFD) при этом помещает очередное сообщение в первый попавшийся контейнер, алгоритм же Best Fit Decreasing (BFD) помещает сообщение в тот контейнер, где после этого останется меньше всего свободного места.

Answer (score -2):

В принципе, данный алгоритм не будет особо сложным. Из всего берется наибольшее число, вычитается из максимума, чтобы понять сколько нам осталось, ищется максимальное число, которое меньше или равно остатку, кладется в контейнер. Опять смотрим сколько еще осталось и снова производим поиск чтобы "забить до потолка". И так с каждым числом. Муторно, но работать должно. Сейчас вот сижу делаю скрипт на пхп чтобы проверить).

Comment: Контейнер вмещает 10. Есть числа: 6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5
По вашему алгоритму будет:  
6+3 = 9  
5+2+2 = 9  
2 = 2  
Три контейнера, хотя можно запихать в два:  
6+2+2, 5+3+2

Comment: Значит, начинаем с середины, и идем переборкой вверх.

Comment: По идее, вообще, еще и проверки, например, берем 6+3, если нет дополнения до максимума, то смотрим 6+2. Если тут максимум набирается, то оставляем так. И так по всем проходить. Но алгоритм будет достаточно долгим.

Comment: Любой алгоритм будет неоптимальным в общем случае. Но может быть максимально приближен к оптимальному при соответствующем усложнении. А те алгоритмы, которые мне посоветовали выше (best fit, first fit) простые, и там есть ограничение сверху по их неоптимальности - википедия пишет что 
Стратегии Best Fit Decreasing и First Fit Decreasing используют не более (11/9)*N + 1 контейнеров (где N - число контейнеров при наилучшем решении задачи).
Вроде как есть более оптимальные решения, но они сложнее так что видимо ограничусь такой точностью.